# How can I pass an array to a method?

Tags: php, arrays, function, oop, parameter-passing

Here is my current code:

```
public function myfunc( $class_name, $method_name, array $params = [] ) {
    $obj = new $class_name();
    if ($obj->$method_name()['status']) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

My current code works as well. Now I need to pass `$params` array to `$method_name()` method. So I use `call_user_func_array` PHP function. Here is my new code:

```
public function myfunc( $class_name, $method_name, array $params = [] ) {
    $obj = new $class_name();
    if (call_user_func_array($obj->$method_name()['status'], $params)) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

But in this version, it throws this error:

> call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given

Can you please tell me how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`call_user_func_array()` invokes a callback (which is an array, function string name)  where the list of parameters is given as an array. you can do

```
call_user_func(array($obj, $method_name), $params)['status']
```

the expression `array($instance, $methodname)` is a representation of a callback in php, namely the the method `$instance->$methodname`.

Comment: Won't work .. it throws *`Call to undefined function method_name()`*

Answer (score 0):

In this code you have to create $params array and initialize it and than pass as argument in function calling. See below code :

```
 $params = array();
 $params[0]=anyVal;
 $params[1]=anyVal;
 $params[n]=anyVal;

 if (call_user_func_array($obj->$method_name()['status'], $params))
 {
    // do stuff
 }
```